# Discord.py Erorr 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Мой код

```
@client.command()
async def iponeargoopelda(ctx):
   with open("id users2.txt") as f:
      data = f.readlines()
      user = client.get_user(data[1])
      await user.send('hey')
```

я получаю ошибку, бот должен получать айди с документа.txt и отпровлять соабщение в лс .

Если вы можете,сделайте так что бы оно отпровляла всем соабщение по айди в документе,у меня все айди по строчно т е:
752773841885069333
592717639105773589
601008862178443267

```
Ignoring exception in command iponeargoopelda:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\Desktop\Nukebot.py", line 28, in iponeargoopelda
    await user.send('hey')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
async def iponeargoopelda(ctx):
   with open("id users2.txt") as f:
      data = f.readlines()
   user = client.get_user(data[0])
   await user.send('hey')
```

Comment: Уже сделал.@client.command()
async def iponergoopelda(ctx):
   for line in range(1 , 30):
      with open("id users2.txt") as f:
         data = f.readlines()
         for line in data:
            user = await client.fetch_user(int(line.strip()))
            await user.send('a')